# OSX - Parental Controls - System Preferences - Unchecked - But Not Blocked - Why?

Tags: mac, osx-leopard, blocking, parental-controls, system-preferences

Why is it that using Parental Controls and unchecking the box for System Preferences sometimes does not block a user from gaining access to System Preferences ?

I have blocked other users accessing System Preferences in the past by unchecking the application from within Parental Controls such that when a user attempts to access System Preferences a prompt will pop up saying:

The application "System Preferences" is not allowed.

This is what I want to replicate, but for some reason is not working on a different system with the same OS.

Comment: Does this happen for all users?

Answer (score 0):

Use the pad lock on the bottom left to require the user to enterthe Administrator's password to change anything

Comment: Hi Luke, that will not prevent a user from gaining access to the System Preferences, and some of the panes will not require unlocking such as Desktop & Screen Saver pane.

Comment: Misunderstood the question, sorry